# Azure VM running processes

Tags: azure, azure-vm

Is it possible to list the running processes from an Azure VM and kill one by name/id?
I'm looking to do it thru API but not sure if it's supported at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Azure VM Run Command functionality to do that.

For Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

For Linux:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command

You can do it on Azure Portal,Azure PowerShell,Azure Cli and [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand)

Comment: It will work, but I need to create the script and execute it to get whatever information I need. But I was looking for something that already exist to not create any files.

Comment: @VadimVisnevski, As far as I know, this is the only way to do that